# Using PDO to set a variable from a MAX query

Tags: php, mysql, variables, pdo

I want to set a variable $item_id from the result of this query, how do I do it?

SELECT FROM item (MAX(item_id) + 1));

I have tried this code, but it isn't giving me a result:

```
$sql = "SELECT FROM item (MAX(item_id) + 1));";
$statement = $db->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute($sql);
$item_id = $statement->fetchColumn();
```

My database connection is named $db and is housed in a common.php file, and all other queries are working, I've tried numerous options but am not having a win.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, fix the query statement, then also, you don't need to feed the query statement inside the `->execute()`, just leave it blank:

```
$sql = "SELECT MAX(item_id) + 1 FROM item;";
$statement = $db->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute(); // no need to add `$sql` here, you can take that out
$item_id = $statement->fetchColumn();
echo $item_id;
```

Comment: Thanks! My head was starting to hurt with all the different things I'd tried!